# two slugs in one url, kwargs and args

Tags: python, django

I want my url to be like 'slug/slug/' 
if they are not combined together each slug works fine but when I try to combine these two, I get into the problem.  I think I can use args and kwargs for this but I don't know how to apply this.

```
path('series/<slug>/', views.season_pg, name='season_detail'),

def season_pg(request, slug, slug):
    series = Series.objects.get(slug=slug)

    season_nr = Season.objects.get(slug=slug)
    content_dict = {
        'season_nr':season_nr
    }
    return render(request, 'series.html', content_dict)
```

Models.py

```
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    tv_or_movie = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    period = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    descritpion = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    #img
    #video

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/" %self.slug




class Season(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    season_nr = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.season_nr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path('series/<slug:serie>/<slug:season>/', views.season_pg, name='season_detail'),

def season_pg(request, serie, season):
    try:
        series = Series.objects.get(slug=serie)
    except Series.DoesNotExist:
        # if no rows found
        series = ''
    try:
        season_nr = Season.objects.get(slug=season)
    except Season.DoesNotExist:
        # if no rows found
        season_nr = ''

    context = {
        'series': series,
        'season_nr':season_nr
    }
    return render(request, 'series.html', context)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be  slug=slug1 and slug=slug2

Comment: I showed you way, to make route with two dynamic parameters. When you send request on server, for example => http://localhost:8000/series/slug_python/slug_django/ => slug1 will be slug_python and slug2 will be slug_django. How you will use this slugs and make queries in database, it's your option.

Comment: ya that's what I want bur ur approach doesnt seem to work

Comment: thanks for the update but I get NoReverseMatch at /how-i-met-your-mother/
Reverse for 'season_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'season1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['series\\/(?P<serie>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/(?P<season>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']

Comment: You are using "named urls" in templates, change slug with serie and season.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=each_season.slug %}">{{each_season}}</a>
im srry how should i change it??

Comment: <a href="{% url 'season_detail' season=each_season.slug %}">{{each_season}}</a>

Comment: You should use same names as they are in function arguments. Mark problem solved, if it's fine...

Good luck !